# Change background color of leaflet popup

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

I use leaflet and react. I need to change some popup styles, for example, a background color.

To open a window I use the code

```
marker.bindPopup(content,{className: 'custom-style'});
```

The main problem is that I get the styles from the backend and it will be different for each popup.

Because styles are different then I can't use this solution

```
.custom-style .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper,
.custom-style .leaflet-popup-tip {
    background-color: #f4913b;
}
```

How to properly assign custom styles to popup?

Comment: I think you're confused - you can define several CSS classes, and apply a different one to each popup by changing the `className` option in the `.bindPopup()` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the Popup HTML Element over `marker.getPopup().getElement()` and then add a style to it.

**It is important to add first the marker to the map and then bind the popup to the marker and open it directly!** After adding the style you can close the popup again.

```
var marker = L.marker(map.getCenter()).addTo(map).bindPopup("Test").openPopup();

marker.getPopup().getElement().children[0].style.background = 'red'; // content
marker.getPopup().getElement().children[1].children[0].style.background = 'red'; // tip

marker.closePopup();
```

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/ll8kjCocyWaueI8y

Answer (score 0):

Just one line of code:

```
background-color: yellow !important;
```

Basically, change this part in the CSS file, and don't forget to add **!important**.

```
.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
background-color: yellow !important;
}
```